# Visual Studio Team Services user can not see the project

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have an free account in Visual Studio Team Services with 5 basic users. i have defined many projects. one of them with the name of Project_1 had 5 Basic users without any problem, after deleting a basic user, I added new user as fifth new user. my new user is active in all team and projects Including Project_1. 
when my fifth new user is logging on, he can see all the projects unless Project_1.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with permissions and security. You could try to give the new user administrator permissions in Project_1 and see whether this has a positive impact. If yes, reduce permissions stepwise to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the new user has required permission to access to Project_1, you can do this via following steps:

1. Check the groups that the new user belong to via command:

   tfssecurity /im  /collection:https://.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
2. Check the permission of groups that the user belong to from webportal. (Open Project -> Click Manage Project Button -> Click Security Panel)

To access to a project, the user need to be a member of the project and have the “View project-level information” at least. You can set the permission accordingly on security page.

By the way, does the new user just cannot see the project from “Recent projects & teams” list on project home page? If yes, click the “Browse” button to see all the projects. The project will be listed in “Recent projects & teams” list after the user open it once.

Comment: Hi, Eddie. new user like other 4 users is a member of  Team-1 in Project-1 . team-1 is a member of Contributors and Project Valid users.  Project Valid users and Contributors are members of VSO Groups of Project-1. No limitation are assigned for new user. his permissions are exactly as like as other 4 users.

Comment: Can the user open the Project_1 directly via URL: https://<your account>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/Project_1?